# Генерация случайных чисел без повторений в боте для Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Пишу простого бота в телеграм, который дает тесты. Как избежать повторений вопросов в тесте?

```
...
numb = rand.random(1,2)
if numb == 1:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Text1")
elif numb == 2:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Text 2")
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "end")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
a = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    a.append(i)
random.shuffle(a)
```

Список ***а*** будет содержать рандомные числа от 1 до 100.
Ну а бот просто пусть задаёт вопросы закодированые под номерами в указанном выше числовом диапазоне.

Comment: список можно без цикла получить: `list(range(1, 101))`. В общем случае, это не поможет избежать повторения вопросов, если перегрузить бот по любой причине.

Comment: Ну если с перезагрузкой бота, то только через бд, других способов я не знаю. P.S. Интересный и простой способ генерировать список, я запомнил, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователю не попадались одинаковые задания - используй любую базу данных, в которую записывай номера вопросов. Код привести не могу, т.к он будет зависеть от прочих потребностей

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/235458)

Comment: @Sublihim: *"используй любую базу данных, в которую записывай номера вопросов"* вполне себе ответ (не слишком полезный из-за краткости, но ответ).